# Insert rows for an m:m relationship (pupil-evening_activity) consistently

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, many-to-many, last-insert-id

I have three tables in my database (MySQL/InnoDB): `pupil`, `evening_activity` and `pupil_evening_activity`. As you can guess there is an `m:m` relationship between `pupil` and `evening_activity`.

I have a HTML form to insert new pupils and associate to them evening activities. After submitting the form, I would like to insert pupils and their associated activities in the database. So I have written this code:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=school;charset=utf8','root', '****');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pupil 
            (name, surname) 
            VALUES
            ('test_name', 'test_surname')";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();

    foreach ($eveningActivityIds as $eveningActivityId) { 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pupil_evening_activity 
                (pupil_id, evening_activity_id) 
                VALUES 
                (?, ?)
        ";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute(array($db->lastInsertId(), $eveningActivityId));
    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {

echo $e->getMessage();
return false;

}
```

I have written that code **expecting `PDO::lastInsertId()` always returns the last inserted pupil's id**, but I've found out that what it really returns is **the last inserted `id` on the whole database**. So if another row is inserted in a hypothetical `teacher` table *just before* calling to `$db->lastInsertId()` on the code above, `$db->lastInsertId()` would return the `id` of the inserted teacher instead of the `id` of the last pupil.

So how I can get 100% safety the last inserted `id` of `pupil` table after submitting the form?

I have thought about using a transaction and `MAX()` function to get last `id` inserted in the `pupil` table, but I'm not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a mistake to have $db->lastInsertId() within the foreach loop, as it may return unpredictable values. Please consider the code below:

```
try {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO pupil 
        (name, surname) 
        VALUES
        ('test_name', 'test_surname')";

   $st = $db->prepare($sql);
   $st->execute();

   // save pupil id into variable here:
   $pupil_id = $db->lastInsertId();

   // also there's no need to prepare the statement on each iteration:
   $sql = "INSERT INTO pupil_evening_activity 
            (pupil_id, evening_activity_id) 
            VALUES 
            (?, ?)";
   $st = $db->prepare($sql);

   foreach ($eveningActivityIds as $eveningActivityId) { 
      $st->execute(array($pupil_id, $eveningActivityId));
   }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
   return false;
}
```

Optimization: you can insert all acivities in one statement. It saves you few requests

```
try {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO pupil 
    (name, surname) 
    VALUES
    ('test_name', 'test_surname')";

  $st = $db->prepare($sql);
  $st->execute();

// save pupil id into variable here:
  $pupil_id = $db->lastInsertId();

  $sql = 'INSERT INTO pupil_evening_activity 
        (pupil_id, evening_activity_id) 
        VALUES '; 

  $values = array();

  foreach ($eveningActivityIds as $eveningActivityId) {
    $sql .= '(?, ?),';
    array_push($values, $pupil_id, $eveningActivityId);
  }

  $st = $db->prepare(chop($sql, ','));
  $st->execute($values);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks! very useful!! but.. any idea about my main question? that is: is it correct using `PDO::lastInsertId()` to get the last `id` inserted in `pupil` table?

Comment: I believe it's fine unless you're building a highloaded system with thousands requests per second J.